# VS Code Jupyter Can't Select Kernel Even Though It Detects It

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Visual Studio Code (VS Code) to work with Jupyter notebooks. I have the Jupyter kernel installed, but when I open a .ipynb file, the kernel is detected but not automatically selected. I've already ensured that everything is up to date and reinstalled the necessary components. What might be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
[Environment Variable Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOHHi.png)
While I can manually select the kernel, it would be more convenient if it could auto-detect the appropriate kernel.

When I attempt to select a kernel, I'm presented with two options:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whraX.png)
Python Environment: This offers two choices: "Python 3.11" (as installed by Python) and "Python 3.10" (installed in the mingw64 folder, which I originally installed for C/C++).
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Restarted VS Code.
Ensured that both VS Code and the Jupyter extension are up to date.
Uninstalled and reinstalled the Jupyter extension.
Checked that the Python environment associated with the kernel is activated.
Is there anything else I can try to make the Jupyter kernel automatically select when I open a .ipynb file in VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Vscode : Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`
Type "jupyter select interpreter to start jupyter server"

Select python(3.x) interpreter.

Restart the Vscode.